# Negative lookbefore in js

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to find up till the end of a line. The line is either \r\n or \r or \n depending on OS.

So to simplify it I thought to start with ha or h or a

so in `blah!` it should give me ['bla', 'a']

However I keep getting ['bla', 'la'] as js doesnt have a negative look before.

I was wondering how to accomplish this.

This was my attempt:

```
var patt = /.*?(ha|h(?!a)|[^h]a)/;
var m = patt.exec('blah!')
```

Comment: You mean *negative look-behind*. If you want to just *find* `a` not preceded with `h`, just use capturing mechanism. What are you trying to achieve as the final goal? To match a line? Just split with `(?:\r\n|\r|\n)`. Note that even inside  1 file there may be various linebreaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to alternate between `ha` and `[^h]a`, if you don't want to match any other symbol preceding `a` than `h`: this...

```
ha|a
```

... is sufficient. Remember, matching in alternation starts from the leftmost option and attempts to cover as much ground as possible. So this:

```
\r\n?|\n
```

... should be enough.